# how to Draw the Voronoi diagram for two distinct points

Tags: draw, diagram, points, voronoi

I am trying to figure how to Draw the Voronoi diagram for two distinct points.

can someone help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As shown in my picture, you should just connect your points, and then draw a line through the center, orthogonal to that segment.

[image: fig]